# How to maximize or fill the whole page with bootstrap carousel. (with navigation bar)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm currently working with my website. My problem is, I cant maximize the size of my bootstrap carousel. My desired output of my website is the whole page is filled with the bootstrap carousel and there is only a navigation bar above the site for navigation menu. I manipulate all the possible attributes of the `<div>` and `<img>` inside my carousel code such as width and height but still the carousel not occupy the whole page. Does the real the size of the image affects?

Comment: You need to post your code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Niel Sinel You can fit it with the whole page but first we need to see your html code.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working in this kind of project. [https://www.webdesignerexpress.com/]
I found a link http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/#.VZOqWPmqqko try it
I guess it will solved our problem.

This is the output page http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/inc.carousel/background-carousel.html

just put navigation bar above I think it will work.

Comment: i will now try to edit the code, i will give the edited code after.